# WordPress site inaccessible - "Site can't be reached" error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, hosting

I am encountering a problem with my WordPress site, and I would appreciate any help in resolving it. When I try to access my site by entering the domain in the browser, or even when trying to access the login page, I receive a "Site can't be reached" error. This issue seemed to occur suddenly as the site was working fine before.

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

I have checked the server logs, and the error log shows PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in /home/gh3qcrr0o0he/public_html/wp-content/plugins/qtranslate-xt-master/qtranslate_core.php on line 462.
I have tried accessing the site from different browsers and devices, but the issue persists.
I have verified the DNS settings, and they seem correct.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try disabling all the plugin by changing the name of the plugins folder and then activate the plugin one by one. It looks like the error message you provided indicates a problem with the qTranslate XT plugin in the file qtranslate_core.php. The "Cannot modify header information" warning typically occurs when there is output sent to the browser before headers are set.

Comment: "You can also reach me for more information" - answers on Stack Overflow should be self contained so future readers can also get help.

Comment: [Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/11107541)

Comment: I tried renaming the plugins folder, but it didn't make any changes